# Random password creation using install shield (install script)

Tags: installshield, installscript

I am new to Install Shield(Install Script), so apologies in advance if my question is repetitive.

Is there any function in install shield to create random password ? 
or a code snippet to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Why not let the person doing the installation choose and enter the password?  Several circumstances spring to mind which makes that preferable such as centralized administration of many machines.

Answer (score 2):

InstallScript doesn't include anything like that built-in. You would need to write your own function to implement the feature. As far as I can see you have the options:

- You can write a DLL that generates (creates) the random password and call this DLL function from your script. This is probably the preferred method as I am not sure what is the "random password"? Is this random number or random sequence of characters, or something else. Anyways you are free to create your own implementation according your requirements.
- You may prototype Windows random generator functions in your script and call them to generate random number. Probably you would need to convert this number into the "password", if this is something else than number. To prototype Windows functions you would need to include `winapi.h` and prototype lines for `rand()` and seed generating `srand()` functions. Something like ...

  ```
  prototype cdecl VOID MSVCRT.srand(INT);
  prototype INT MSVCRT.rand();
  ```